# Typescript Issue on Discriminated Union

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, types, discriminated-union

I am trying to write a simple factory function with discriminated unions to create new instance of a class. However I haven't found any way that satisfies my requirements.

- I want to pass platform as extra parameter or inside of the data object or even as generic to function but I would like to be able to understand instance type of object right after I create object (intellisense should understand if it's telegram or whatsapp instance & shows properties etc.)

```js
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

type Gender = "male" | "female" | "nonBinary";
type Platform = "telegram" | "whatsapp";
type City = "myLocation" | "amsterdam" | "barcelona" | "berlin" | "brussels" | "buenosAires" | "capeTown" | "copenhagen" | "chicago" | "dubai" | "gothenburg" | "helsinki" | "hongKong" | "istanbul" | "kualaLumpur" | "kyiv" | "lisbon" | "london" | "losAngeles" | "madrid" | "malmo" | "manchester" | "melbourne" | "milan" | "montreal" | "newYork" | "oslo" | "paris" | "reykjavik" | "rio" | "rome" | "sanFrancisco" | "saoPaulo" | "singapore" | "stockholm" | "sydney" | "toronto" | "vienna" | "zurich";
type BodyType = "thin" | "athletic" | "average" | "extraPounds" | "bigTall";
type Education = "none" | "highSchool" | "college" | "bachelors" | "masters" | "phDPostDoctoral";


interface IUser {
    userId?: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
    gender: Gender;
}

class User implements IUser {
    readonly userId: string;
    readonly name: string;
    readonly age: number;
    readonly gender: Gender;

    constructor(props: { name: string, age: number, gender: Gender, userId?: string }) {
        this.userId = props.userId || uuidv4();
        this.name = props.name
        this.age = props.age
        this.gender = props.gender
    }

    public get ID(): string | undefined {
        return this.userId;
    }
}

interface TelegramMeta {
    telegramId: number;
    job: string;
    bodyType?: BodyType,
    height?: number,
    children?: boolean,
    smoker?: boolean,
    education?: Education,
    educationName?: string,
    about?: string,
    favouriteCities?: string,
    placesToGo?: string,
    freeTime?: string
}

interface ITelegramUser extends IUser {
    platform: "telegram",
    telegramMeta: TelegramMeta,
}

class TelegramUser extends User implements ITelegramUser {
    readonly platform = "telegram"
    telegramMeta: TelegramMeta;

    constructor(props: { name: string, age: number, gender: Gender, telegramMeta: TelegramMeta, userId?: string }) {
        super(props);
        this.telegramMeta = props.telegramMeta;
    }
}

interface WhatsappMeta {
    whatsappId: string,
    intagramLinks?: string[]
}

interface IWhatsappUser extends IUser {
    platform: "whatsapp",
    whatsappMeta: WhatsappMeta,
}

class WhatsappUser extends User {
    readonly platform = "whatsapp"

    whatsappMeta: WhatsappMeta;

    constructor(props: { name: string, age: number, gender: Gender, whatsappMeta: WhatsappMeta, userId?: string }) {
        super(props);
        this.whatsappMeta = props.whatsappMeta;
    }
}

type UserTypes = ITelegramUser | IWhatsappUser;
type UserPlatforms = UserTypes['platform'];

type ReturnTypeLookup = {
    "telegram": ITelegramUser;
    "whatsapp": IWhatsappUser;
};

type SchemaFor<T extends UserTypes> = ReturnTypeLookup[T['platform']];

export function createUser<T extends UserTypes>(data: T): SchemaFor<T> {
    if (data.platform === 'telegram') {
        return new TelegramUser(data);
    } 
    return new WhatsappUser(data);
}

const telegramUser = createUser<ITelegramUser>({
    name: "Harrison",
    age: 30,
    gender: "male",
    platform: "telegram",
    telegramMeta: {
        telegramId: 123,
        job: 'Developer'
    },
});
```

It gives this error message:

```
Type 'TelegramUser' is not assignable to type 'SchemaFor<T>'.
  Type 'TelegramUser' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    The intersection 'ITelegramUser & IWhatsappUser' was reduced to 'never' because property 'platform' has conflicting types in some constituents.
```

TLDR Example: https://tsplay.dev/wEPMyW

Comment: Could you reduce that to a [mre]?  Most issues should be reproducible in 30 lines of code or less.  Like, you can just `Foo` and `Bar` with a few properties in each, and get rid of the class implementations.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, I believe it's pretty simple already ?

Comment: You don't know how to reduce it?  You can remove so much of it and still reproduce the issue.  [Here you go](https://tsplay.dev/wEPMyW), that's a lot smaller and it has the same issue, right?  If you agree, I can work on solving it. If you don't agree, let me know and I'll go elsewhere.

Comment: I think you probably want the output type to be different from the input type in general, right?  Currently you have `Foo` in and `Foo` out.  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdAznm) seem like a good example of the general issue?

Comment: If so, then this looks like a case of [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the supported way to deal with this is a significant refactor as mentioned in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The refactor for my example looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ4eow).  If this meets your needs I will write up an answer.  But I might [edit] your question first to put the minimal example, as plain text, in the question.  The "telegram or whatsapp" aspect of this doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: well maybe I basically want output to be based on the input. So this are all fine to me:
createUser<Telegram> (data) -> returns Telegram instance
createUser("telegram", data) -> returns Telegram instance
createUser(data/**Includes platform**/) -> returns Telegram instance.

Comment: Sorry I had to go back to my example to visualize in my head I guess it worked like [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/j9cxkp) (sorry playground link was so big).But I didn't understand this method well. What is this method called ? I thought discriminated unions were the only way to achieve this type of operation

Comment: I'm happy to explain in my answer, if you agree that it works for you.  I tend to write long answers so I like to be sure, before I start, that I won't have to go back and edit the whole thing.  So a straightforward "yes, that approach meets my needs, please write it up and explain" or "no, that doesn't work because of xyz" would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes totally it worked :D

Answer (score 4):

Let me paraphrase what you're trying to do and the problem you're running into.  You have a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

```
interface Foo {
    type: "foo",
    fooMeta: { a: string }
}

interface Bar {
    type: "bar",
    barMeta: { b: number }
}

type Types = Foo | Bar;
```

And you have some functions that map each member of this union to some corresponding output type:

```
declare function doFoo(data: Foo): number;
declare function doBar(data: Bar): Date;
```

You'd like to package these into a single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function that accepts any member of the discriminated union and delegates to the corresponding function, and returns the corresponding function's return type:

```
type ReturnLookup = {
    "foo": number;
    "bar": Date;
};    

declare function create<T extends Types>(data: T): ReturnLookup[T['type']];

const doneFoo = create({ type: "foo", fooMeta: { a: "" } }); // number
const doneBar = create({ type: "bar", barMeta: { b: 123 } }); // Date
```

But, unfortunately, you can't seem to implement this function without getting type errors:

```
export function create<T extends Types>(data: T): ReturnLookup[T['type']] {
    if (data.type === 'foo') {
        return doFoo(data) // number is not assignable to number & Date
    }
    return doBar(data) // Date is not assignable to number & Date
}
```

Why is this happening and how can you fix it?

---

This is happening because the compiler cannot narrow the type parameter `T` when you check the value `data` of type `T`.  Checking `data.type` narrows `data`, but it does not affect `T` itself.  Since `T` is not affected inside the function implementation, the compiler never knows whether you should return the return type of `doFoo` or the return type of `doBar`.  The only thing it would see as safe is if you somehow returned a value of *both* types, that is, the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of both types.  And that's why you get errors about `number` or `Date` not being assignable to the intersection `number & Date`.

There are various issues in GitHub that mention this problem and request ways to fix it.  One is [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014), where it is suggested that there be some way to narrow the generic type parameter `T`.

Another is [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), which deals with correlated union types, and the recommended fix for this issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) gives a way forward here, if you're willing to refactor:

---

The refactoring is to change your discriminated union to an object type whose keys are the discriminant property and whose property values are the rest of the members:

```
interface TypeMapping {
    foo: {
        fooMeta: { a: string }
    },
    bar: {
        barMeta: { b: number }
    }
}
```

Then, instead of defining `Types` as a union, you define it as a *distributive object type* where you make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and immediately [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a union:

```
type Types<K extends keyof TypeMapping = keyof TypeMapping> =
    { [P in K]: { type: P } & TypeMapping[P] }[K]

type Foo = Types<"foo">
type Bar = Types<"bar">
```

The types `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Types` types are equivalent to the ones at the top (note that `Types` without the generic argument evaluates to `Types<keyof TypeMapping>` due to the [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)), but now the compiler explicitly sees the relationship between `Types<K>` and the union members of `K`.

Then we can package the `doFoo` and `doBar` functions into a single object whose type is also explicitly represented in terms of the keys of `TypeMapping`:

```
const funcs: { [P in keyof TypeMapping]: (data: Types<P>) => ReturnLookup[P] } = {
    foo: doFoo,
    bar: doBar
}
```

And this representation is important.  It allows the compiler to understand that, for a value `data` of type `Types<K>` for generic `K`, you can call `funcs[data.type](data)` and get the output type `ReturnLookup[K]`:

```
export function create<K extends keyof TypeMapping>(
    data: Types<K>
): ReturnLookup[K] {
    return funcs[data.type](data); // okay
}

const doneFoo = create({ type: "foo", fooMeta: { a: "" } }); // number
const doneBar = create({ type: "bar", barMeta: { b: 123 } }); // Date
```

So there's no error there, hooray!

---

But take note, the reason this works has very much to do with the exact representation of the types here.  If, for example, you remove the annotation of `funcs` above:

```
const funcs = {
    foo: doFoo,
    bar: doBar
}
```

Then the error comes back:

```
return funcs[data.type](data); // error, number | Date not number & Date
```

That's because the compiler loses the connection between the type of `funcs[data.type]` and that of `data` (which is the whole topic of microsoft/TypeScript#30581), and you might as well not have refactored at all.

So be careful with this technique!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFATgewEYBsJiQG8BYAKDKUqQEtgAXCNAMwWQDEMMiKre6BPGBABcSAERNOYgDQ9elSRgCyEOiFGEk6pFDppaAcyQBfOSbJnaDZqyQAhEGm6l5VAUNFisjmWd7e0FTUNJCxRYABXMCxGcxcqU3J4yndkABVBaCQAXiQOLgAfe0cAbgtkpFSkACVVCLRgABlOAGsImBznV0oJKXComLQyit4vH1EAERAGYd5jYbMAEwh4HEdkJgjgeDpqDGAkRYx8gApF6e18gEp+6MZZqmXV9aRN7d39w4wHNDOL0R+NyQUxm5V4AHpwYcVms0Bstjs9gd4HDphAADxpJAQAAeDGAiygSAyQigAD4-sFiUDanR6k1Wu0ANppJkAclSbIAulyFhVcTAMGg6K8ER9kaiGJjsXiIASiSToBTzlS0jS6g1mhg2jAWezOTyut1qEwkJSQAA6KrZG1INmKNlXI3dKhwukNL6nFUgJ2QpCRO5OahE4AYEUgKBQagGUC4ZB0LgBwZIABkwLRfgSmcobvpXx+5t9UJByGD-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)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with similar issue and your idea of extracting type in this way was helpful

```
type Types<K extends keyof TypeMapping = keyof TypeMapping> =
    { [P in K]: { type: P } & TypeMapping[P] }[K]
```

I'd like to note however that it is possible to simplify by using generic and replacing these fragments:

```
const funcs: { [P in keyof TypeMapping]: (data: Types<P>) => ReturnLookup[P] } = {
    foo: doFoo,
    bar: doBar
}
```

```
declare function doFoo(data: Foo): number;
declare function doBar(data: Bar): Date;
```

```
type Foo = Types<"foo">
type Bar = Types<"bar">
```

with this:

```
declare function doTypeFn<K extends keyof TypeMapping>(data: Types<K>): ReturnLookup[K];
```

full example:

```
interface TypeMapping {
    foo: {
        fooMeta: { a: string }
    },
    bar: {
        barMeta: { b: number }
    }
}
type Types<K extends keyof TypeMapping = keyof TypeMapping> =
    { [P in K]: { type: P } & TypeMapping[P] }[K]

type ReturnLookup = {
    "foo": number;
    "bar": string;
};

declare function doTypeFn<K extends keyof TypeMapping>(data: Types<K>): ReturnLookup[K];

export function create<K extends keyof TypeMapping>(
    data: Types<K>
): ReturnLookup[K] {
    return doTypeFn<K>(data); // okay
}

const doneFoo = create({ type: "foo", fooMeta: { a: '' } }); // number
const doneBar = create({ type: "bar", barMeta: { b: 1 } }); // Date
```